# ValueError : I/O operation on closed file (File is already opened?)

Tags: python, valueerror

**ValueError : I/O operation on closed file**

Hi, I'm getting this error in my code. I've tried googling this, and I understand what the error means, but I don't understand why I get this error. I'm still learning python, so this probably is a basic error.

```
for line in file:
    if line == tekstNaamLogin:
        file.close()
        file2 = open (filename2, 'r+')
        for line in file2:
            if line == tekstWwLogin:
                weergaveinlog = Label(root, text = "Succesvol ingelogd!" + tekstNaamLogin)
                weergaveinlog.grid(row=4, sticky=W, column =1)
                print ("Succesvol ingelogd als: " + tekstNaamLogin)
                file2.close()
                time.sleep(2)
                vergeetinlog()
                weergaveinlog.grid_forget()
                start()
            else:
                 print ("Wachtwoord onjuist!")

    else:
        print ("Gebruikersnaam onjuist!")
        file = open (filename, 'r+')
        print ("Uw gebruikersnaam is: " + line)
        file.close()
```

The error occurs in this part:

```
for line in file2:
```

I just don't understand what's wrong, because file 2 is opened right before reading it.

Thanks for the help

Comment: You are closing`file2` on the first iteration. The second iteration now sees the file has been closed but need it open. Try to uae the `with open(...) as file2:` control structure to auto-close the file.

Comment: The same as Klaus D has commented will happen on the first loop when you solve the first issue, if there is more than 1 line in the first file. If you want finish the iteration when you find the line, you should use `break`